# How to move a player object with JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

How can I access the Player object that I create in my main class called `Program` with a JButton created inside a class called `Die`?

The direction that I'm going right now(after experimenting with a lot different ways) is to create the ActionListener in a seperate class called `ButtonListener`.

Inside of my `Player` class is a method that I'd like to invoke with the JButton:

```
public void roll(int steps) {
    setSteps(steps);
    System.out.println("Rolled: " + steps);
    move();
}
```

Inside my `Die` class I construct the JButton:

```
public class Die extends JPanel {

private List<Integer> die = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private ImageIcon  one, two, three, roll;
Random rand = new Random();
int dieValue = 0;
Player player = new Player();

 JButton dieButton;

/**
 * Constructor for creating the die button
 */
public Die(){
    addNumbersToDie();
    setDieImages();
    dieButton = new JButton();
    dieButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    dieButton.setIcon(roll);
    add(dieButton);
}
```

And here is my `ButtonListener` class:

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        //Call out the roll() method.
    }
}
```

The ActionListener works fine when the button is pressed, but I haven't find a solution how to call the `roll(int steps)` method inside the `Player` class...

I could create the button in Player class, but that would be too messy, so I'm in the search of a better way.

The whole idea is to make the player move with my JButton.

Added code from my main class called `Program`:

```
// Create board.
    Board board = new Board();

    // Create new player.
    Player player = new Player();

    // Add player to start.
    board.getStart().enterField(player);

    // Check if player is on board.
    drawBoard(board);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a constructor for your listener that will take a player as parameter.

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    private Player p;

    public ButtonListener(Player p){
      this.p = p;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        p.roll();
    }
}
```

Then just do :

```
dieButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(player));
```

Comment: Only problem with this is that I create a new Player called p, but I need to make the Player called player defined in the main Program class to move.
Also because I add the player object to my Board object(added code from my Program class to my question).

Comment: But do you have one button/player or what ? I don't get what you mean.. =) Could you clarify this please ?

Comment: I thought I explained it but yes, I have one player and one button.

Comment: So what's the problem of creating a `Button` for each player and set the actionListener like I described ?

Comment: Got it to work after some changes in the code, thanks!

Not sure why I got the downvotes though..